# Windows Phone Loading a large number of images from IsolatedStorage to JumpList

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a more then 1000 images (thumbs) in the IsolatedStorage and need to show them at JumpList

I have a XAML code:

```
<telerikData:RadJumpList   telerikCore:InteractionEffectManager.IsInteractionEnabled="True" Name="TitleCollection" ItemsSource="{Binding TitleCollection}">
<telerikData:RadJumpList.ItemTemplate >
 <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                    
        <Image Source= "{Binding Cover}" CacheMode="BitmapCache" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstLine}" />                                        
    <StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

and model

```
 public class TitleList : ViewModelBase
{      
    public String Id_on_server { get; set; }

    public String FirstLine
    {
        get;set;        
    } 

    private static Mutex _mut = new Mutex(false,"mutex control");

    BitmapImage _Cover;

   public BitmapImage Cover
    {
        get
        {             
            if (_Cover == null)
            {
                BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
                bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
                    (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) =>
                    {
                        String fileName = App.ImageDirectory + "/" + this.Id_on_server + "_front_thumb.jpg";
                        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                        {
                            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                            {
                                if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        _Cover = new BitmapImage();
                                        _Cover.SetSource(myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    _Cover = new BitmapImage();
                                    _Cover.UriSource = new System.Uri("/Image/Movie.Icon.Default.png", System.UriKind.Relative);                                       
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });

                bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
                    (object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) =>
                    {
                        _mut.ReleaseMutex();
                        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
                        {
                            RaisePropertyChanged("Cover");
                        });
                    }
                    );

                _mut.WaitOne();
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
            }

            return _Cover;
        }
        set
        {
            _Cover = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Cover");
        }
    }
}
```

So I get images from isolated storage in background and show in the list.
This code works but If JumpList is scrolling quickly strong delay in showing items is happend.

Can anyone advise how to correctly display a large number of pictures or make competent LoadDelay like LowProfileImageLoader. 
Any advice or example will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In my project I use [Kawagoe Toolkit](http://kawagoe.codeplex.com/) for similar task.

In your code, only 1 line of your code is executed in the background thread:

```
String fileName = App.ImageDirectory + "/" + this.Id_on_server + "_front_thumb.jpg";
```

The rest of your code, including the file I/O, is executed in the UI thread, which is wrong. One way to fix:

```
public class TitleList : ViewModelBase
{
    public String Id_on_server { get; set; }

    BitmapImage _Cover;

    static MemoryStream readImage(string id)
    {
        String fileName = Path.Combine( App.ImageDirectory, this.Id_on_server + "_front_thumb.jpg" );
        using( IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication() )
        {
            if( !myIsolatedStorage.FileExists( fileName ) )
                return null;
            try
            {
                using( var stm = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile( fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read ) )
                {
                    var ms = new MemoryStream();
                    stm.CopyTo( ms );
                    return ms;
                }
            }
            catch( Exception ex )
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( ex.Message );
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public BitmapImage Cover
    {
        get
        {
            if( null != _Cover )
                return _Cover;

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( s => 
            {
                var ms = readImage( Id_on_server );
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => 
                {
                    var img = new BitmapImage();
                    if( null == ms )
                        img.UriSource = new Uri( "/Image/Movie.Icon.Default.png", System.UriKind.Relative );
                    else
                        img.SetSource( ms );
                    _Cover = img;
                    RaisePropertyChanged( "Cover" );
                } );
            } );
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why file reading is so slow on Wp7.5?  When I scrolled list of 500 items to the and  I'm  waiting too long time while images are shown completly. Do you know any possibilities to stop loading images which  are outside of the screen. So if I scrolled to number 500, it wouldn't  start load of 1-490, but during scroll, cancel those, and quicker get to display the 490-500 that I see on screen.